# Create/Update array data to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to update data properly. I have messed around as much as possible and can't seem to figure it out properly.
I'd appreciate any help in javascript

Data
`{"KEWCFN": {"dataId": "KEWCFN","dataName": "12","dataSet": []}}`

I want to be able to be able to properly update that JSON data to this.

`{"KEWCFN": {"dataId": "KEWCFN","dataName": "12","dataSet": [{set1....},{set2....},{set3....}]}}`

Comment: To update a file on a server from a client (eg browser) you would need to send the updated JSON string to the server containing the file and have some server side script update it. You will need to update your question to contain more information on what you need done, from where, and any attempts you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Hey im not sure understand your question but if you want to change dataSet in your data Array  then you can do this:

```
Function updateMe(){

Var Data = {"KEWCFN": {"dataId": "KEWCFN","dataName":"12","dataSet": []}} ;

    Data.dataSet[0]=‘set1....’;
    Data.dataSet[1]=‘set2....’;
    Data.dataSet[2]=‘set3....’;
}
```